# How to invoke AMAZON.HelpIntent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on an Alexa skill for declension of German nouns. Recently I've submitted a beta version for the certification review. The skill failed the review, one of the issues was with help message:

> The skill does not return a help prompt that instructs users on how to navigate further into the skill’s core functionality.
>
> Steps to Reproduce:
> User: "Alexa, starte deutsche deklination"
> Skill: " Welches Wort soll ich deklinieren? "
> User: "hilfe"
> The skill closes the session and there is no tts response.

Ok, I get the critique, but I fail to reproduce this in Test section of the Alexa Developer Console. I've tried the described "Steps to Reproduce". The skill is invoked with "starte deutsche deklination" as it should be. But then when I input "hilfe", the skill does not seem to be invoked at all. This is how it looks in the Alexa Developer Console:

[image: Trying "Steps to Reproduce" in Alexa Developer Console]

As you can see, Skill I/O is empty. I can also confirm that the skill lambda function is not invoked as there are no log messages in CloudWatch log stream.

I'm completely puzzled. How do I actuall invoke `AMAZON.HelpIntent`?
"Steps to Reproduce" suggested in Amazon Certification Feedback does not seem to work - at least not in Alexa Developer Console.

---

If this helps, my skill is open source and can be found here:

https://github.com/highsource/declension-alexa-skill-lambda

AMAZON.HelpIntent handler:

https://github.com/highsource/declension-alexa-skill-lambda/blob/master/index.js#L199-L203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well sometimes I also had these kind of issues.

- How is your skill reacting if you use it with a real device?
- Sometimes for me it helped when I rebuild the model.
- your are sure that you do not end your session after Launch intent?

**Update**

- just saw that you also used the word "Hilfe" in your model: https://github.com/highsource/declension-alexa-skill-lambda/blob/master/models/DE_SUBSTANTIV-values.csv It could be that Alexa is not confident which intent to choose because of this
- So give it a try without this substantive.
- You can also have a look in "Build -> Utterance Conflicts" if this conflict appears there.

Comment: You were right. I've resolved all the utterance conflicts (by removing entries from `DE_SUBSTANTIV`) and now `Hilfe`, `Stopp` and `Abbrechen` work fine.
Adding `hilfe` to `AMAZON.HelpIntent` utterances was not necessary (and AWS support advised against it).

Comment: ok, awaiting your published skill ;-). I updated my answer and removed the advice to add Hilfe to the AMAZON.HelpIntent

Comment: [Published](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0829CTT8B/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=deutsch+deklination&qid=1575451966&s=digital-skills&sr=1-1)!.